# UWP: Toast localization

Tags: uwp, localization, resources, toast

In my solution I use a separate Class Library as a localization resource and in my views I use it by the following way:

[image]

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        ...
        <localization:LocalizedStrings x:Key="localizer"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

...

```
<AppBarButton Icon="Back" Label="{Binding Strings.Back, Source={StaticResource localizer}}" Command="{Binding UpToEventViewCommand}"/>
```

How can I localize my toast notifications? I tried to use ms-resource Uri like in the tutorial (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/tile-toast-language-scale-contrast) but it doesn't work in this case.

Can I remap my-resource or use another way to localize my toast notifications?

**UPDATE**:

LocalizedStrings is like just a manager for my string resources:

```
public class LocalizedStrings
{
    public LocalizedStrings() { }

    private static readonly Strings LocalizedStringsResources = new Strings();

    public Strings Strings => LocalizedStringsResources;
}
```

Comment: Could you show more detail about `LocalizedStrings` class or share a mini sample that I could check the detail ?

Answer (score 0):

You can acess your class like this

```
var localizer = Application.Current.Resources["localizer"] as LocalizedStrings;
```

And then access everything that you want

```
toast.Text = localizer.String.ToastText;
```